# I am unable to deploy my platypi demo app

Tags: node.js, ant, gruntjs

I have been following the instructions on how to get started with platypi on https://platypi.io/docs/getting-started.
Everything was going well, until I tried to create the deployment package (https://platypi.io/docs/getting-started/1251/Deploy-to-a-Device).

When I run the node command "grunt build-cordova" I get the following error: "Error: Failed to run 'ant -version'...".  So I tried installing ant first by entering the command "npm install node-ant".
However, when I do so, I get an error saying that I need to have Visual Studio 2010 build tools installed.

I do not want to install VS 2010 just to install ant, since I already have VS 2013 and 2015 installed.
My question is:  How can I get the grunt command "grunt build-cordova" to work without installing VS 2010?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try installing Ant directly from the [site](https://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi)?

Download the binary and put it somewhere on your computer (I used C:\apache-ant-1.9.4), then add the path to the installed location to your PATH environment variable. You can find out how to do that [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml), the instructions are for java, but it works for other variables.

I added an `ANT_HOME` environment variable with a value of "C:\apache-ant-1.9.4". Then I edited my `Path` to include `%ANT_HOME%;` at the end.

Afterwards you will need to restart any open command prompts. You may also have to run `npm uninstall node-ant` to avoid conflicts.